# AFNetworking и обработка ответов сервера

Tags: objective-c, ios, afnetworking

Каким образом и где в коде можно обрабатывать ответы с сервера при запросах через AFNetworking? В интернете не нашел подробного и полного примера.

Интересуют ситуации: 1) превышен тайм-аут ответа (например, 5 секунд сервер не отвечает из-за плохого интернета), 2) отсутствует интернет совсем, 3) ошибка в работе скрипта на удаленном сервере, 4) внутренняя ошибка сервера / профилактика.. итп. Самые-самые распространенные причины.

Хочу в зависимости от кода ответа открывать разные AlertView.

Пример запроса:

```
NSString * URL = @"http://supersite.ru/script.php";
NSURL * nsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URL];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsURL];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationFeedback = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
operationFeedback.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[operationFeedback setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id JSONResponse){

// ... тут обработка ответа

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *err)
{

// ... а тут видимо нужно обработать код ответа?!

}];
[operationFeedback start];
```

Comment: // ... а тут видимо нужно обработать код ответа?! Тут напишите NSLog(@"Error: %@", err); . В ошибке будет полное описание проблемы, а так же коды ошибок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, вы правильно написали, в блок `failure` вы получите объект класса `NSError`, и вам нужно обработать его содержимое - `.domain` и `.code`. Коды сетевых ошибок можно посмотреть в [Foundation Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/URL_Loading_System_Error_Codes) или еще проще – используя cmd+клик на уже набранной константе, например `NSURLErrorResourceUnavailable`, ошибки там удобно собраны кучкой